# Consistent estimate vs out-of-sample performance

Tags: time-series, cross-validation, cross-correlation, dynamic-regression

When there is a cross-correlation structure in linear regression errors, the usual approach is to model the errors as an ARIMA process. It leads to a consistent estimate of the parameters of the model.

However, for a few examples, I get better out-of-sample performance using a simple linear model when compared to linear model with ARIMA error. Even though linear model + ARIMA fits the data better and gives a lower AIC value.

What model should I prefer simple linear model or linear model + ARIMA?

Comment: How do you measure out-of-sample performance?